# Problems using Springboot autoconfiguration to connect to SQL-Server in a FUSE EAP environment

Tags: spring-boot, sql-server-2012, redhat, jbossfuse, jboss-eap-7

This is likely to be a misconception on my part when it comes to working with SpringBoot on FUSE EAP environments. I've been trying to deploy a service, which I've developed following the RedHat documentation and the archetypes/examples I've found online that mix Camel and SpringBoot, but to no avail.

From what I understand, when creating a connection to a JNDI datasource, which has been configured and tested in the EAP Fuse server, I can use the application.properties, or application.yml, to have the spring application autoconfigure the connection. In my case, it's required that I use @PersistenceContext to invoke the EntityManager, since the CRUD operations that the extending JpaRepository don't really cover the needs.

As per RedHat's documentation, FUSE 7.2 has been installed in EAP 7.1 and the POM is using the org.jboss.redhat-fuse.fuse-springboot-bom version 7.2.0.fuse-720020-redhat-00001.

I've tried using spring's autoconfiguration, a manual configuration declaring a @Configuration class, a manual configuration by declaring the database connection in the camel-context.xml file, and some other minor tests.

The errors vary depending on whether I try delpying the .jar or .jar.original, generated by having the spring-boot-maven-plugin with the repackage execution goal, errors obtained up to this point are:

- NullPointer because EntityManager em is null (.jar.original)
- java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryBuilder (.jar.original, when there's a manual configuration of the datasource, be it in a @Configuration annotated java class, or in the camel-context.xml using Spring DSL)
- java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dao.genericDAOImpl (.jar with all dependencies packaged)

Here are snippets of my program, which include the POM, Application.java and the component which is trying to get the EntityManager, will be happy to provide more snippets if it's not enough/unclear.

POM.xml

```
...
    <properties>
        <fuse.version>7.2.0.fuse-720020-redhat-00001</fuse.version>
        ...
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.camel</groupId>
            <artifactId>camel-spring-boot-starter</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-actuator</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
    </dependencies>
...
<build>
        <defaultGoal>spring-boot:run</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            ...
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>1.5.16.RELEASE</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>repackage</goal>
                        </goals>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            ...
        </plugins>
    </build>
...
```

application.properties

```
spring.datasource.jndi-name=jdbc:sqlserver://ip:1433;DatabaseName=dbname
spring.jpa.hibernate.dialect=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.hibernate.naming.implicit-strategy=org.hibernate.boot.model.naming.ImplicitNamingStrategyLegacyJpaImpl
spring.jpa.show-sql=true
spring.jpa.database-platform=org.hibernate.dialect.SQLServer2012Dialect
spring.jpa.generate-ddl=false
```

Application.java

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/camel-context.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

camel-context.xml

```
<beans ...>
...
    <camelContext id="identidades_financieras" xmlns="http://camel.apache.org/schema/spring">
        <onException>
            <exception>java.lang.Exception</exception>
            <handled>
                <constant>true</constant>
            </handled>
            <setHeader headerName="Exchange.HTTP_RESPONSE_CODE">
                <constant>500</constant>
            </setHeader>
            <setBody>
                <simple>${exception.message}</simple>
            </setBody>
        </onException>
        <restConfiguration apiContextPath="/openapi.json"
            bindingMode="json" component="undertow"
            contextPath="/restservice/api_v1" enableCORS="true">
            <dataFormatProperty key="prettyPrint" value="true"/>
        </restConfiguration>
        <rest enableCORS="true" id="rest-for-openapi-document" path="/openapi">
            <get id="openapi.json" produces="application/json" uri="openapi.json">
                <description>Gets the OpenAPI document for this service</description>
                <route id="route-for-openapi-document">
                    <setHeader headerName="Exchange.CONTENT_TYPE" id="setHeader-for-openapi-document">
                        <constant>application/vnd.oai.openapi+json</constant>
                    </setHeader>
                    <setBody id="setBody-for-openapi-document">
                        <constant>resource:classpath:openapi.json</constant>
                    </setBody>
                </route>
            </get>
        </rest>
        <rest bindingMode="auto" enableCORS="true"
            id="rest-b5d099c1-1996-458b-b5db-34aadc57a548" path="/">
            <get id="customPaginatexxxVO" produces="application/json" uri="/xxx">
                <to uri="direct:customPaginatexxxVO"/>
            </get>
...

        <route id="route-28f4489d-b354-401b-b774-6425bec1c120">
            <from id="from-17c4205f-8d28-4d3d-a265-cb1c38c9bc32" uri="direct:customPaginatexxxVO"/>
            <log id="customPaginatexxxVO-log-1" message="headers ====> pageSize: ${header.pageSize} - pageNumber: ${header.pageNumber}"/>
            <bean id="to-ee6565efaf-de46-4941-b119-be7aaa07d892"
                method="paginate" ref="genericService"/>
            <log id="customPaginatexxxVO-log-2" message="${body}"/>
        </route>
<beans/>
```

genericService.java

```
@Service
public class genericServiceImpl implements genericService {

    @Autowired
    private genericDAO dao;
    ...
    @Override
    public xxxVO paginate(Map<String, Object> reqHeaders) {
        ... pageProps are defined using reqHeaders ...
        xxxVO paginated = dao.customPagination(pageProps);
        return paginated;
    }
    ...
}
```

genericDAOImpl.java, which errors out when anything regarding em is invoked.

```
@Repository
public class genericDAOImpl implements genericDAO {

    @PersistenceContext //when manually configured, I've added the (unitName="") in reference to the persistence unit, from my understanding, since only one datasource was created, this should pick up by default
    private EntityManager em;
...
    @Override
    public xxxVO customPagination(paginateProps pageProps) {
        xxxVO result = null;
        try {
            CriteriaBuilder paginationBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder();
            CriteriaQuery<T> paginationQuery = paginationBuilder.createQuery(entity.class);
            Root<T> entityClass = paginationQuery.from(entity.class);
            paginationQuery.select(entityClass);
            ... some settings with pageProps ...
            TypedQuery<T> query = em.createQuery(paginationQuery);
            entityList = query.getResultList();
            ... entityList is transformed to xxxVO ...
        } catch (Exception e) {
            LOG.error("caught something");
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        return result;
    }   
...
```

As stated before, I've been getting numerous different errors depending on the options I've tried, and most of them clearly come down to misconfiguration, or not deploying correctly, I'm still somewhat inexperienced when it comes to SpringBoot and Camel, and different things I've read on the internet have created some confusion. Just to make sure, the pagination method, while very snipped out, should be working, if it had a not nulled EntityManager.

Here are a couple of the logs:

When deplying .jar (fat jar with all dependencies), which from the tests I've made, deploys correctly using java -jar, but not in the fuse eap service

```
09:16:01,937 WARN  [org.springframework.context.support.GenericApplicationContext] (MSC service thread 1-3) Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.dao.genericDAOImpl] for bean with name 'genericDAO' defined in URL [vfs:/content/identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/spring/camel-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dao.genericDAOImpl from [Module "deployment.identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader]
09:16:01,940 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-3) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".CamelContextActivationService."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".CamelContextActivationService."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar": Cannot create camel context: identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.service.CamelContextActivationService.start(CamelContextActivationService.java:71)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.CannotLoadBeanClassException: Cannot find class [com.example.dao.genericDAOImpl] for bean with name 'genericDAO' defined in URL [vfs:/content/identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar/BOOT-INF/classes/spring/camel-context.xml]; nested exception is java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: com.example.dao.genericDAO from [Module "deployment.identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader]
...
```

When deploying .jar.original (basically, just the java) with a manually configured DataSource and EntityManagerFactory. From what I understand, the service is expecting org.springframework.boot dependencies to exist on the server. After checking the modules, there is no org.springframework.boot module in the fuse layer. Is this intended?

```
09:50:17,265 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] (MSC service thread 1-8) MSC000001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment.unit."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".CamelContextActivationService."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar": org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar".CamelContextActivationService."identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar": Failed to start service
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1978)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1149)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:624)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
Caused by: java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/springframework/boot/orm/jpa/EntityManagerFactoryBuilder
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods0(Native Method)
    at java.lang.Class.privateGetDeclaredMethods(Class.java:2701)
    at java.lang.Class.getDeclaredMethods(Class.java:1975)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:613)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:524)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.doWithMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:510)
    at org.springframework.util.ReflectionUtils.getUniqueDeclaredMethods(ReflectionUtils.java:570)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.getTypeForFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:697)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.determineTargetType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:640)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.predictBeanType(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:609)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.isFactoryBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1490)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doGetBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:425)
    at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanNamesForType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:395)
    at org.springframework.context.support.PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(PostProcessorRegistrationDelegate.java:96)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.invokeBeanFactoryPostProcessors(AbstractApplicationContext.java:687)
    at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:525)
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.SpringCamelContextBootstrap$1.run(SpringCamelContextBootstrap.java:90)
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.proxy.ProxyUtils$1.invoke(ProxyUtils.java:51)
    at com.sun.proxy.$Proxy68.run(Unknown Source)
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.proxy.ProxyUtils.invokeProxied(ProxyUtils.java:55)
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.SpringCamelContextBootstrap.createSpringCamelContexts(SpringCamelContextBootstrap.java:87)
    at org.wildfly.extension.camel.service.CamelContextActivationService.start(CamelContextActivationService.java:58)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:2032)
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1955)
    ... 3 more
Caused by: java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.springframework.boot.orm.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryBuilder from [Module "deployment.identidades_financieras-1.0-SNAPSHOT.jar" from Service Module Loader]
    at org.jboss.modules.ModuleClassLoader.findClass(ModuleClassLoader.java:198)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClassUnchecked(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:412)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.performLoadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:400)
    at org.jboss.modules.ConcurrentClassLoader.loadClass(ConcurrentClassLoader.java:116)
    ... 27 more
```

Finally, when uploading the .jar.original using only the Spring autoconfigure, the EM is null, using Postman I get a status 500 and "No response available" when I consume the REST

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
at com.example.dao.genericDAOImpl.customPagination(GenericDAOImpl.java:252)
```

The line makes reference to CriteriaBuilder paginationBuilder = em.getCriteriaBuilder(), or any other place where a EM method is invoked.

Thank you for your time! Any comment is appreciated...

Answer (score 2):

There is no support for Spring Boot with Fuse EAP and the Camel subsystem. Hence why you do not see any `org.springframework.boot` dependencies in the Fuse module layer.

If you are going to deploy Camel Spring Boot applications into EAP, it's best you either disable the Camel subsystem for your deployment or avoid installing the subsystem entirely.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. that's quite the news to me, specially since the RedHat documentation for Fuse 7.0 has a chapter called: CHAPTER 5. APACHE CAMEL IN SPRING BOOT, and they recommend the use of a BOM called fabric8-project-bom-camel-spring-boot, which as far as I understand, is imported in the BOM I used for my project. I'll be wary about the support then.

Answer (score 0):

This is by no means a solution to the issue I was having, I believe this to be but a temporary patch on my code since the 7.4 version of Fuse will supposedly support SpringBoot 2.1.x or something of the like, but doing the following allowed me to create the database connection and move on with my life. I will not mark this as the acceptable answer, unless I'm told that this is the only way.

In the Application.java, I straight up disabled the SpringBootServletInitializer. Full disclosure, I straight up have no idea of the impact that doing this could have in an application, but the dependency was troubling while I was trying to deploy.

```
@ImportResource({"classpath:spring/camel-context.xml"})
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application {//extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }
}
```

I created a persistence.xml file where I configured the name of persistence unit and selected the package containing the entities (or listed them, both worked).

In the camel-context.xml I declared the following before the  tag

```
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.component.jpa.JpaComponent" id="jpa">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTxManager"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.JpaTransactionManager" id="jpaTxManager">
        <property name="entityManagerFactory" ref="entityManagerFactory"/>
    </bean>
    <bean
        class="org.springframework.orm.jpa.LocalEntityManagerFactoryBean" id="entityManagerFactory">
        <property name="persistenceUnitName" value="PERSISTENCE UNIT NAME IN PERSISTENCE.XML"/>
    </bean>
    <bean class="org.apache.camel.spring.spi.SpringTransactionPolicy" id="requiredPolicy">
        <property name="transactionManager" ref="jpaTxManager"/>
        <property name="propagationBehaviorName" value="PROPAGATION_REQUIRED"/>
    </bean>
```

I created a java class responsible for the creation of the EntityManager, it is very important that the class is @Stateless (EJB), and that the connection to the persistence unit is made static.

```
@Stateless
public class persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl implements IfEntityManager{


    private static EntityManager em;

    static {
        EntityManagerFactory entityManagerFactory = Persistence.createEntityManagerFactory("PERSISTENCE UNIT NAME");
        em = entityManagerFactory.createEntityManager();
    }

    public void setEntityManager( EntityManager em ) {
        persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl.em = em;
    }

    public EntityManager getEntityManager() {
        return persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl.em;
    }
}
```

In the beans where the database connection was needed, in my case, an @Component (should work just as well in a @Repository), I added the following:

```
    private IfEntityManagerImpl IfEntityManager;

    @PostConstruct
    public void init() {
         this.persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl = new persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl();
     }
```

And whenever the EntityManager needs to be called, I can use persistenceUnitEntityManagerImpl.getEntityManager()

Just to make sure that the component isn't creating a new connection/entity manager/whatever, you can add a LOG to the @PostConstruct init, if your bean is a singleton (should be by default, I believe) you will never get that LOG or printline.